# What does it mean when Redshift gives you "invalid end key specified" on a dynamo table load?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redshift

Doing a dynamo load into redshift I got this error that didn't show up in the Redshift docs or  as a literal string into google at all.

```
# copy redshift_table_name from 'dynamodb://DYANAMOTABLENAME' credentials 'aws_access_key_id=XXXX;aws_secret_access_key=YYY' readratio 98;
ERROR:  Invalid end Key specified
DETAIL:
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Invalid end Key specified
  code:      9005
  context:   Table Name = DYNAMOTABLENAME
  query:     1042978
  location:  table_dynamodb_scanner.cpp:242
  process:   query0_s0_26 [pid=21105]
  -----------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 6):

This happens when the hashkey or rangekey in the dynamo table don't have corresponding columns in the redshift table.  Make sure they exactly match in name and have suitable types.

Comment: I'm using exactly same name and suitable types in redshift still getting error.

Answer (score 0):

Add partition key and ensure column order and type matches. It should work. Missing  partition key would result in this